Automatic encryption key generation and upload for CoreML models?
I've created a TensorFlow model which I then convert to a CoreML model using the Apple coremltools Python package for use in an iOS app. My current workflow is:

Generate the model and convert to CoreML format using a script
Manually open the generated model and generate an encryption key by using the UI (see screenshot)
Add the generated key to Xcode using a script.
Xcode automatically encrypts the model using the compiler flag --encrypt "$SRCROOT/App/Resources/Models/MyModel.mlmodelkey" when building the app

Automate Encryption
I often have to make changes and improvements to my model for each app release and would like to automate the generation of the encryption key, so it can be added to Xcode.
It's possible to encrypt a CoreML model using the following terminal command:
xcrun coremlcompiler compile <model.{mlmodel,mlpackage}> </desired/path/to/output/directory> --encrypt <path/to/model_key_file> 
Using xcrun coremlcompiler --help I have not yet found a way to generate an encryption key automatically and it appears that it has to be done by the UI.

Is it possible to generate an encryption key for CoreML models using the command line or some other automation method?
Upload Key to Apple's Servers
In an ideal scenario I would like to also like to be able to encrypt the model in the terminal using the generated key before it gets to Xcode. This can be achieved by the --encrypt command parameter:
xcrun coremlcompiler compile <model.{mlmodel,mlpackage}> </desired/path/to/output/directory> --encrypt <path/to/model_key_file> 
Since the encryption key is downloaded to the user's device from Apple servers, can this encryption key be somehow uploaded when supplying a pre-encrypted model to Xcode (e.g. as part of a framework)?

In the (extremely sparse) documentation they also fail to mention that using that compile flag is going to make the model unusable in simulator. Have you noticed "Model Deployment", still referenced in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/generating_a_model_encryption_key and WWDC keynotes, has vanished without a trace? Now the solution is "just download it, compile, and serve" but it's a PITA building a practical CI around it.
